# Docker run : Logs not displayed on the console

Tags: logging, docker

Following is the Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:centos6
MAINTAINER Priyanka

################## Helpful utils
RUN yum -y install sudo
RUN yum -y install curl
RUN yum -y install unzip

################## JDK7

#Note that ADD uncompresses this tarball automatically
ADD jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt
WORKDIR /opt/jdk1.7.0_79
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java 1
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/jar 1
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javac 1
RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_79" >> /etc/environment
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Xms1024m -Xmx4196m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m

RUN curl -O http://10.113.57.164:8080/job/ROC4-Server-UT-enabled/ws/roc-server-bootstrap/target/bootstrap.zip
RUN unzip bootstrap.zip -d /usr/share/server
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/server/bootstrap/bin/bootstrap.sh
CMD ["/usr/share/server/bootstrap/bin/bootstrap.sh","run"]
```

Following are the docker commands used :

```
docker build -t serdock9 .

docker run -v /priyanka_docker/configserver.properties:/usr/share/server/bootstrap/config/configserver.properties serdock9 /bin/bash
```

Docker build is running successfully. 
When I execute Docker run, the command executes,but does not show any logs on the console.
Where as, the same bootstrap.sh when i run on manually shows a set of logs.
Any idea as to what should be updated for the logs to show up as I'm not being able to determine the status of Docker run without them.

Comment: Are you sure it is `/bin/bash` in the end of `run` command?

Comment: with your `docker run` you replace CMD with /bin/bash, so it is "normal" there is no log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your Dockerfile has a line

`CMD ["/usr/share/server/bootstrap/bin/bootstrap.sh","run"]`

this means that a

`docker run -v aaa:bbb serdock9`

will launch this script

when you launch

`docker run -v aaa:bbb serdock9 /bin/bash`

you replace your CMD by /bin/bash, which does not display anything

see also

https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs/

extract

`I define an alias
alias nethogs='docker run -it --net=host --rm k3ck3c/nethogs'
so just
nethogs
will monitor wlan0
and
nethogs eth0
will monitor eth0 (or accordingly ra1, or...)`

Comment: Understood../bin/bash was added as an alternative to shebang [#!/bin/bash] in .sh file..now i have removed it and instead added ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"] in the dockerfile...works fine..